# Desde hace unas dos semanas no logro que los programas en shiny se ejecuten en rstudio

Tags: r, shiny

[image: corrí este ejemplo de shiny muy sencillo y me sigue dando el mismo problema]Tengo mas de un año usando shiny en r studio y primera vez que se me presenta este problema y en realidad tengo varios dias tratando de solucionarlo. Cualquier otro código se me jecuta sin problema, pero cuando ejecuto un código con shiny, no se ejecuta el programa y debo reiniciarlo o interumpir la sesion. [image: Cuando corro el código no se ejecuta el programa y no avanza mas de este status]

Comment: Bienvenido jesus ramon a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: La imagen que pones no aporta ninguna información útil, salvo por el hecho de que la solapa de Viewer esta totalmente en blanco, te diría que no hay nada que muestre que el código tiene alguna falla. Así que es poco o nada la que podemos decirte. Yo intentaría 1) Crear una nueva app shiny, la que se genera automáticamente (creo que es la del histograma del geiser) 2) Prueba esa App ¿Te muestra algo? 3) Si no ves nada prueba ejecutar esa misma app no en la solapa del Viewer sino en un Navegador independiente, en Run App podes elegir de que forma ejecutarla

Comment: Ahora que lo veo mejor, el problema es que Rstudio no te identifica el script como una App de Shiny, si lo hiciera tendrías el botón "Run App" y no el clásico "Run".

Comment: Prueba ejecutar así `shiny::runApp('path_al_script.R')`